# Stack Overflow technology and Q&A engine

Tags: discussion, api, stack-overflow, technology

I just love the technology and design underlying Stack Overflow. They way questions are written, answered, evaluated, the way users get reputation and privileges, how tags are created in a [folksonomic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folksonomy) way, etc.

I wonder if Stack Exchange has made part of this technology available to webmasters who would like to add a similar Question & Answer (Q&A) engine to their sites. I have seen that Stack Exchange has an [API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage), but as far as I know it is just for querying the websites and databases owned by the Stack Exchange team.

Does anybody know if Stack Exchange has released its Q&A engine, or if there is any similar technology available for free?

Comment: I suggest you look at http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

There are few questions & answers from owner of this site, [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)

Stack Overflow didn't release its engine but there are several [clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

You can read about what is Stack Overflow made with [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/)

Answer (score 1):

The source code is not open source (or free) and is not likely to be any time soon.

There are many clones out there, some are probably free.

If you want to suggest a new stack exchange site, look at [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).